# reloadData doesn't reload the table view in completion handler's dispatch_async to the main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, mapkit, reloaddata

I'm using a UISearchBar to do a MKLocalSearch with Swift 1.2 in iOS 8 (simulator).

I get the results returned in the completion handler (see it in the console via printlns), but when I try to do an async call the main thread to reload the table view nothing happens.

If I click cancel in the search bar it will then show the results in the table view. It seem that I'm doing the async reload data call wrong.

Here is my code for the UISearchBarDelegate searchBarSearchButtonClicked:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    if let currentLocation = appDelegate.currentLocation {
        searchResults.removeAll()

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
        request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation.coordinate, 200, 200)

        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

        search.startWithCompletionHandler({ (response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
                println("No matches found")
            } else {
                println("Matches found")

                for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
                    println("Name = \(item.name)")

                    self.searchResults.append(item)
                }

                println("Matching items = \(self.searchResults.count)")
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.searchTableView.reloadData() // doesn't do anything
            })
        })
    }

}
```

Here is an example of what I am seeing in the console, but with a still empty table view:

```
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
numberOfRowsInSection called
searchBarSearchButtonClicked called
startWithCompletionHandler called
Matches found
Name = Artichoke Basille's Pizza
Name = Scott's Pizza Tours
Name = Waldy's Wood Fired Pizza & Penne
Name = Trattoria Zero Otto Nove
Name = Vezzo Thin Crust Pizza
Name = Grimaldi's
Name = Tappo Thin Crust Pizza
Name = Mozzarelli's
Name = NY Pizza Suprema
Name = Otto Enoteca Pizzeria
Matching items = 10
numberOfRowsInSection called
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Artichoke Basille's Pizza
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Scott's Pizza Tours
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Waldy's Wood Fired Pizza & Penne
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Trattoria Zero Otto Nove
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Vezzo Thin Crust Pizza
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Grimaldi's
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Tappo Thin Crust Pizza
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Mozzarelli's
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = NY Pizza Suprema
cellForRowAtIndexPath called, name = Otto Enoteca Pizzeria
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: added some more printlns to show the different table delegate methods were being called and updated the console output above.

Comment: Does `searchTableView` have its `delegate` defined?

Comment: Yes, the delegate of searchTableView and searchBar is the table view controller.

Comment: Are your table view data source methods being called? ie. `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Try putting `self.searchTableView.reloadData()` immediate after `for` loop(above println).

Comment: @FrequencyMatched, unfortunately that doesn't help. It just shows double the calls to numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath, but no change in the table display.

Comment: There is a potential data race caused by the line `self.searchResults.append(item)` in the completion handler - where the `searchResults` object may be accessed from two different threads concurrently. This is likely not the reason for your issue, but you should fix it anyway: use a temporary array where you collect the items, then in the code dispatched to the main thread, assign this temp array the `searchResults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so your log would appear to show that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is getting called properly and that it's successfully retrieving the data. So, now the question is why you're not seeing it in the table.

Either `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't populating the right controls, or the `frame` (or `alpha` or something like that) for those controls are set such that you can't see the data. Pause execution by hitting the "pause" button in Xcode:

[image]

and look at the layout of the views, either in the new view debugger:

[image]

or by typing `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` at the `(lldb)` prompt. Confirm the `frame` of the the text label that you're populating with the data that you logged.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting tip! I had accidentally added the Search Bar Controller (deprecated?) to the scene alongside the other controller. Once I deleted that it didn't have the nice 'cancel' button anymore (just an 'x'), but it properly displayed the table view with the list from MapKit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that can't call `UITableView.reloadData()` from a main thread. Instead of that, you need to schedule your own thread and call it Asynchronously.

So, first you need to schedule your own created thread and call it from background. You can go with the following code to reload your UITableView data.

```
let concurrentQueue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", nil)

dispatch_async(concurrentQueue) {
                            // update some UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

     // update some UI
     self.tableView.reloadData()
         }
   }
```

Well, this will definitely reload your UITableView data. As far as, I know, I am using this method. Let me know, if you find any other method which works more conveniently.

Comment: He's not calling `reloadData` from background queue. He's already dispatched it back to the main queue.

Comment: @Rob Oh! it's my bad! when you call dispatch_get_main_queue() you actually get back the main thread. Update the answer and that's the reason I have created my own thread to reload data!

Comment: You may have misunderstood my point: I agree with you that you must call `reloadData` from main thread (so if you're doing something on background queue, dispatch it back to main queue). My point was merely that the OP is already doing that, so that's clearly not the problem here. The problem rests elsewhere.